# How to match a regexp

Tags: regex, perl, scripting

I want to match a string with a Perl regexp but my code always fails to match.

#### Data

```
Functions    0.0% (0/1)Functions and exits    0.0% (0/2)Calls    0.0% (0/6)Statement blocks    0.0% (0/24)Implicit blocks    0.0% (0/2)Decisions    0.0% (0/26)Basic conditions    0.0% (0/39)
```

#### Regexp

```
.*([A-Z][a-z]*\s*[0-9]*\.[0-9]*%\s*\([0-9]*\/[0-9]*\)).*
```

This seems to work on several regexp testing websites.

#### Perl code

```perl
my $regexp = ".*([A-Z][a-z]*\s*[0-9]*\.[0-9]*%\s*\([0-9]*\/[0-9]*\)).*";

if ( $myString =~ /$regexp/i ) {     # $myString has the value shown above
    print "Regexp OK\n";
}
else {
    print "Regexp KO\n";
}
```

The result of executing this code always leads to the `else` block but I don't understand why.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!! It would have identified your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using double quotes when you define your regex. That means that `\s` will be interpolated as an escape sequence, and that breaks your pattern.

Use [`qr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html) instead.

```
my $regexp = qr/.*([A-Z][a-z]*\s*[0-9]*\.[0-9]*%\s*\([0-9]*\/[0-9]*\)).*/;
```

If you had `use warnings`, you'd get this warning.

> Unrecognized escape \s passed through

If you print the compiled regex with

```
my $regexp = ".*([A-Z][a-z]*\s*[0-9]*\.[0-9]*%\s*\([0-9]*\/[0-9]*\)).*";
print qr/$regexp/;
```

you will see this output.

```
#                no backslash here
#                 V
(?^:.*([A-Z][a-z]*s*[0-9]*.[0-9]*%s*([0-9]*/[0-9]*)).*)
```

With the backslash gone, the regex engine doesn't know you're talking about whitespace, and sees a literal `s` instead.